# How to generate a swift3 API SDK using WSO2 Api manager

Tags: wso2, swagger, wso2-api-manager

Is there a way to generate swift3 client SDK from wso2 api manager store?
I tried this configuration in api-manager.xml but it leads to a NullPointerException when I try to download the SDK:

```
<SupportedLanguages>swift3</SupportedLanguages>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following are the supported languages for API Manager 2.1

```
android
java
scala
csharp
cpp
dart
flash
go
groovy
javascript
jmeter
nodejs
perl
php
python
ruby
swift
clojure
aspNet5
asyncScala
spring
csharpDotNet2
haskell
```